# animation-timeline: view(); not working in Elementor

Tags: css, wordpress, elementor

I'm trying to do some scroll animation in my WordPress (Elementor) website. So I added some CSS in the Custom CSS option, but it doesn't work. It's showing an error in this line: `Unknown property 'animation-timeline'.`

[This is a snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gQpPv.png) that shows the error in context.
Thanks in advance.

Here is the code which I'm using:

```
selector .chrome4{
    animation: zoom-fade-in linear forwards;
    animation-timeline: view();
    animation-range: entry;
}

@keyframes chrome4{
    0%{
    transform: translatey(400px);
    }
    
    100%{
    transform: translatey(0px);    
    }
}
```

Comment: What version of Chrome are you using? https://caniuse.com/?search=animation-timeline - this property wasn't added until version 115.

Comment: Try translateY instead of translatey

Comment: hi, thanks for the respose. i am using Version 122.0.6261.112 of chrome

Comment: Nothing happened with translateY. i posted a screenshot where the problem is marked exactly.

Comment: the problem shows in these two lines : animation-timeline: view();
    animation-range: entry;

Comment: Did you try view(inline)

Comment: i tried but nothing happened

Comment: It is a new property, is it possible that Elementor just doesn't support it yet.

Comment: I have seen a video tutorial with elementor and it was working. But in my case no